# How can this be modified to show 2 videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vimeo

I found this code online that will show the most recent video from a Vimeo account...

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/VIMEO-ACCOUNT-NAME/videos.json?callback=?',     {format: "json"}, function(videoList) {
        $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/' + videoList[0].id + '&byline=false&portrait=false&callback=?', {format: "json"}, 
        function(videoProperties) {
            document.getElementById("vimeoRecent").innerHTML=videoProperties.html
            document.getElementById("vimeoDescription").innerHTML="<p><a href='" + videoList[0].url + "'>" + videoProperties.title + "</a> from <a href='" + videoProperties.author_url + "'>" + videoProperties.author_name + "</a> on <a href='http://vimeo.com'>Vimeo</a>.</p><p>" + videoProperties.description + "</p>"
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get it to display the 2 most recent videos, instead of one. I tried to add another item to the array e.g. [0,1], but that just breaks the script.

Can anyone suggest how I could get this script to display 2 videos? Thanks!

Here's a non-functioning [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz75U/) just to show the code more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the second getJSON for the second element using `videoList[1].id`, and inserting it into other `div`s

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/VIMEO-ACCOUNT-NAME/videos.json?callback=?',     {format: "json"}, function(videoList) {
        $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/' + videoList[0].id + '&byline=false&portrait=false&callback=?', {format: "json"}, 
        function(videoProperties) {
            document.getElementById("vimeoRecent").innerHTML=videoProperties.html
            document.getElementById("vimeoDescription").innerHTML="<p><a href='" + videoList[0].url + "'>" + videoProperties.title + "</a> from <a href='" + videoProperties.author_url + "'>" + videoProperties.author_name + "</a> on <a href='http://vimeo.com'>Vimeo</a>.</p><p>" + videoProperties.description + "</p>"
        });

//get second video (insert into another div)

        $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/' + videoList[1].id + '&byline=false&portrait=false&callback=?', {format: "json"}, 
        function(videoProperties) {
            document.getElementById("vimeoRecent2").innerHTML=videoProperties.html
            document.getElementById("vimeoDescription2").innerHTML="<p><a href='" + videoList[1].url + "'>" + videoProperties.title + "</a> from <a href='" + videoProperties.author_url + "'>" + videoProperties.author_name + "</a> on <a href='http://vimeo.com'>Vimeo</a>.</p><p>" + videoProperties.description + "</p>"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Izzey, but that doesn't seem to work... just returns a blank screen

Comment: Perfect! It was the IDs that I was screwing up... forgot that they can only be used once. Thank you!!